# how to set default time zone in stored procedure MySql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

Can anybody can share what is the syntax of date_default_time_zone for Stored Procedures?

anyway I have this function called

```
NOW()
```

to get the date and time and stored it into database but if I'm not mistaken it's getting the server time.

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The date/time is derived from the operating system of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server is running.

You could however have a custom UDF that you would call instead of getdate() and then do the timezone change in that UDF. You can also assign default values to columns with something like this

```
CREATE TABLE Test (Val DATETIME DEFAULT  dateadd(hh,-3,GETDATE()))
```

Now when you do an insert it will use the default

```
INSERT test DEFAULT VALUES

SELECT * FROM test
```

....this of course won't work on updates and also someone could update that value

If you want to use GMT then use `GETUTCDATE`

```
SELECT GETUTCDATE()
```

Comment: how to implement this using phpmyadmin?

Comment: thank you for the answer. anyway, is there any way that I don't need to store that time or create new table for that?